# Is there any way to get iPhone App record

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia

Is there any method to get List of Applications` record of last execute date that  installed in iPhone?

of course on developing in Cydia App

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Flurry API in your app. It tracks things for you like installs and how many times an app is used. http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html

Comment: Thank you I`ll find how to use it~

Comment: but i mean get list of All applications in iPhone.. not only my app

Comment: Oh. I see. Sorry I am not sure how to answer that one then. :(